# .slice is not a function error while trying to display data from an api

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a project using React and redux toolkit as state manager. It involves consuming APIs and displaying their data to a front-facing view. I had setup redux-toolkit and I made sure I was getting data from the API before displaying it. Even in postman I could still see the API working currently. This data is first sliced using .slice() and also mapped using .map() to display the data in chunks of 10 per page. Initially, everything worked; I could see the data and also chunk them as well. However, at some point, the data wasn't displaying and I started getting ".slice() is not a function" at the console. I investigated redux via chrome and I observed that no data was fetched. a console.log in the code block showed that I wasn't getting any data as well. I also pasted the endpoint I was consuming on postman and I was getting the data but I could not get it in my redux setup. I need help retrieving the data from the endpoint. Here is my setup:

```js
const List = () => {
  const { loading, list } = useSelector((state) => ({
    ...state.list,
  }));
  const [mockData, setMockData] = useState(list[0]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log(list);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getList());
  }, [dispatch]);


  const dataPerPage = 10;
  const dataPageVisited = pageNum * dataPerPage;

  const displayData = mockData.slice(dataPageVisited, dataPageVisited + dataPerPage).map((datum) => (
    <tr key={datum.id}>
      <td className="text-sm leading-5 py-4 px-3">{datum.id}</td>
      <td className="py-4 uppercase text-center">{datum.name}</td>
      <td className="py-4 pr-4 pl-20">
        {datum.status === 'Active' ? (
          <span className="flex items-center bg-green-300 py-0.3 px-0.2 w-14 rounded-xl text-white">
            <GoPrimitiveDot className="text-white" />
            {datum.status}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span className="flex items-center bg-red-400 py-0.3 px-0.2 w-16 rounded-xl text-white">
            <GoPrimitiveDot className="text-white" />
            {datum.status}
          </span>
        )}
      </td>
      <td className="py-4 pl-4">{datum.websiteUrl}</td>
      <td className="py-4 pl-10">
        <span className="inline-block text-textTeams py-0.5 px-0.4 w-16 bg-indigo-50 rounded-lg text-center hover:cursor-pointer">
          {datum.category}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td className="py-4 px-6">
        <span className="flex justify-between">
          <button type="button">
            <FiSearch className="search-icon hover:cursor-pointer w-5 h-5 text-searchColor" />
          </button>
          <RiDeleteBinLine
            className="delete-icon hover:cursor-pointer w-5 h-5 text-binColor"
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
          />
          <button type="button">
            <FiEdit2 className="pen-icon hover:cursor-pointer w-5 h-5 text-penColor" />
          </button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));



return(

<>
{displayData}
</>
)

}
```

Here is the redux:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getList = createAsyncThunk('list/getList', async (_id) => fetch('http://13.xx.94.xx/neon/api/v1/List/RetrieveAll').then((res) => res.json()));

const listSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'list', 
  initialState: {
    list: [],
    loading: false,
  },

  reducers: {
  },

  extraReducers: {
    [getList.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getList.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.list = [action.payload];
    },
    [getList.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    
    
    
    
  },
});

export default listSlice.reducer;
```

Here is the store:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ListReducer from './features/listSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    list: ListReducer,
  },
});
```

Comment: Try `mockData?.slice`

Comment: yeah I did that result is still the same.

Comment: It seems that your selector is wrong, `mockData` is not arrary, but probably an object. Rewrite that selector.

Comment: This issue isn't about mockData at the moment. The issue is that no data is even coming into mockData. That no data is fetched from the API into redux. But on postman the endpoint works well.

Comment: More just help with debugging, but you said it worked then it didn't. So retrace your steps. What has changed since the last time it ran? Are you using source control and have a working version? Is it possible that the URL for the API request has changed? Is the API call failing within your code and you'd want to add in error handling there?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the issue:

```js
const { loading, list } = useSelector((state) => ({
    ...state.list,
  }));
```

it should have been something like this:

```js
const list = useSelector((state) => state.list.list);
```

also the previous getList:

```js
[getList.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.list = [action.payload];
    },
```

was converted to:

```js
[getList.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.list = action.payload;
    },
```

How don't understand how it worked initially but after refactoring it to the above I started getting the data once again. Thanks again for the insight and help.